# How to Hide a Fragment included in a BaseActivity layout from a specific Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbaractivity

Here is my issue, I am working on the Ads integration for my Mobile Application.

In order to display a banner, I have created a **BannerFragment**.

I want to display this banner in all of my Activities, so that I have included it in a **ActionBarAbstractActivity** layout.

[image: Result on the screen]

[image: Code Layout]

This allow me to display my Banner on all of my Activities without working on their XML files.

But, I have one specific Activity where I don't want to display Ads.

That's why I need to hide the Banner in this Activity. How can I access the BannerFragment in this Activity even if it's not referenced in its XML layout ?

I tried to find the Fragment by ID and hide it, but it's not working.

Should I create my proper banner container for this activty and set the visibility to "HIDE" or "GONE" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the visibility property of the linear layout itself to hide/show the fragment.

Use an id for the **LinearLayout** in the XML.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/bannerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
    <fragment
     ..
     .. 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity,

```
LinearLayout  bannerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bannerLayout);
```

To hide the layout,

```
bannerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // Or in this case, View.GONE will also work
```

To show the layout,

```
bannerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use include the xml of fragment instead of hide or gone.

like this

/>